# Combo headphone/microphone splitter does not work on Ubuntu 18.04, individually plugging in headphone or microphone does

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, microphone

So I can plug either my external lavalier microphone or my headphones *directly* into my Lenovo T450s laptop's single 3.5mm jack, and they both work using the **Built-in Audio = Stereo Analog Duplex** setting in `pavucontrol`:

[image]

When I unplug the microphone after having it directly in the jack, the input device port correctly changes to "Built-in microphone" under the Input Devices tab. And it correctly changes back when I plug it back in.

I purchased [this microphone and headset combo jack](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B073ZCWDZY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which splits the single 3.5mm jack on my computer into a headset output and a microphone input, but I cannot get the microphone to work through it. The audio out of the splitter works just fine, and the microphone even shows up under `pavucontrol` when it's plugged into the mic input of the splitter, but it does not seem to register any sound when I use the exact same `gnome-alsamixer` settings as the ones that worked when the microphone was plugged in directly.

Based on research I've tried adding the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` but neither makes a difference:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
```

and separately,

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-dmic
```

Is there anything else I should be looking at? Thanks.